# Kafka 0.10.1.0 Test Server: Request METADATA failed

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting basic errors after setting up a super simple single-instance Kafka VM. This is for tiny volume development testing.

This is using the latest Confluent Platform 3.1.1 which includes the almost latest Kafka 0.10.1.0.

FYI, a slightly newer bug patch Kafka 0.10.1.1 is out, but the next post 3.1.1 Confluent Platform binary that includes that isn't available quite yet.

I configure `/etc/kafka/server.properties` with (I'm using a static local IP for dev testing simplicity):

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.50.20:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.50.20:9092
```

(is that right?)

Simple console admin commands are generating errors. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the basic setup/configuration.

```
~$ /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
Error while executing consumer group command Request METADATA failed on brokers List(localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null))
java.lang.RuntimeException: Request METADATA failed on brokers List(localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null))
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.sendAnyNode(AdminClient.scala:67)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.findAllBrokers(AdminClient.scala:87)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.listAllGroups(AdminClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.listAllGroupsFlattened(AdminClient.scala:117)
    at kafka.admin.AdminClient.listAllConsumerGroupsFlattened(AdminClient.scala:121)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$KafkaConsumerGroupService.list(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:304)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:66)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
```

**EDIT**: The problem, thanks to Gondola_Ride, was that I specified the IP in `listeners` in `server.properties`. I could connect via that IP, but not via `localhost`. The solution was to use host `0.0.0.0` which is Kafka's convention for binding to all local TCP interfaces:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.50.20:9092
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an entry in the `/etc/hosts` on the host where you are running this command for `this` host `192.168.50.20` and see if it works

Something like

`127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost`

OR

`192.168.50.20  hostname hostname-alias`

Then try using it in the command

OR

Try using `ip address` directly in the command instead of `localhost`

Comment: With direct `ip address` there is no confusion as to whom to contact. But `localhost` may have go thru some mapping which may not be available. Did you check your `/etc/hosts` contents ?